# Multidimensional array looping

Tags: api, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am working with steam api to loop through items in my backpack.  Here is part of what I am returned.

```
{
"result": {
    "status": 1,
    "num_backpack_slots": 900,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1828738510,
            "original_id": 1828738510,
            "defindex": 166,
            "level": 5,
            "quality": 6,
            "inventory": 2147484295,
            "quantity": 1,
            "origin": 0,
            "flag_cannot_trade": true,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 143,
                    "value": 1373392596,
                    "float_value": 118276915200.000000
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 292,
                    "value": 1115684864,
                    "float_value": 64.000000
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 388,
                    "value": 1115684864,
                    "float_value": 64.000000
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 153,
                    "value": 1065353216,
                    "float_value": 1.000000
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "id": 1828947755,
            "original_id": 1178542060,
            "defindex": 5009,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 6,
            "inventory": 2147484021,
            "quantity": 1,
            "origin": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 1828947766,
            "original_id": 1179066746,
            "defindex": 5005,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 6,
            "inventory": 2147483798,
            "quantity": 1,
            "origin": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 1828947780,
            "original_id": 1181421843,
            "defindex": 5009,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 6,
            "inventory": 2147484020,
            "quantity": 1,
            "origin": 4
        },
```

And so on.

What I would like to do is loop through this for my defindex using foreach(or something else that works).  Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$api = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?      key=MyApiKey&steamid=MySteamId&format=json";

$json = (file_get_contents($api));

$schema = json_decode($json);

$total_metal = 0;

if ($schema-> result -> items[0] -> defindex == 5000)
{
     $total_metal++;
}
if ($schema-> result -> items[0] -> defindex == 5001)
{
 $total_metal+= 3;
}
if ($schema-> result -> items[0] -> defindex == 5002)
{
     $total_metal+= 9;
}

print $total_metal;
?>
```

So far this returns 0 since the first variable is not any of these defindexes in this first one.  What I need to do is have these 3 instances go through the whole array.  From what I see I need to write a for each inside a for each but looking around I was not able to find anything that would help me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through each item in your `$schema`. You can do this with a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
foreach ($schema as $item)
```

In this loop, you will check the `$item->defindex` value against the three values you care about (`5000`, `5001`, `5002`).

```
$metal_array = array(5000, 5001, 5002);
```

If it matches one of these values, then you will perform the appropriate math.

```
if (in_array($metal_array, $item->defindex)
{
    switch ($item->defindex)
    {
        case 5000:
           $total_metal++;     // or $total_metal += 1;
           break;
        case 5001:
           $total_metal += 3;
           break;
        case 5002:
           $total_metal += 9;
           break;
    }
}
```

This entire `if` block is in your foreach loop. At the end of the loop, `$total_metal` should contain the amount of metal in your backpack.

Answer (score 0):

well if foreach doesn't work what about

```
for($i = 0; $i < ($schema-> result-> items.length; i++){
    if ($schema-> result -> items[i] -> defindex == 5000)
    {
         $total_metal++;
    }
    if ($schema-> result -> items[i] -> defindex == 5001)
    {
         $total_metal+= 3;
     }
    if ($schema-> result -> items[i] -> defindex == 5002)
    {
      $total_metal+= 9;
    }
}
```

if that doesn't work (because you can't access length for some reason) you can also do this:

```
$i = 0;
while($schema -> result -> items[i]){
      //do stuff
      $i++;
}
```